# Requests hanging on ports forwarded from docker container inside vagrant

Tags: networking, vagrant, docker

So I have a setup very similar to [this one](http://ochronus.com/docker-primer-django/) where I have a docker container running a web service inside of vagrant.

When trying to make a request to the web service on the forwarded port in the docker container from *inside vagrant*, everything works fine, but when trying to make the request from outside, on my local box, the request just hangs forever. Also- it only hangs if the docker container is running, if it is not then the request just fails immediately as normal.

I am forwarding the vagrant ports via:

`config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000`

and the docker ports via:

`docker run -p 3000:3000`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you start your django service. I guess you left the host as default. Try to use something like `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` to set the host name as `0.0.0.0`